# HTML/CSS Container Width

Tags: html, css, inheritance, width, containers

I am having trouble inheriting a width of a parent container(or setting it at 100%). 
I would appreciate if someone could point out a solution, 
I included this JSFiddle for reference. 
https://jsfiddle.net/bawmcnLf/1/

I think the issue springs up from the padding atributes.

```
<div class="bg-container">
   <h1>
    SOME LORUM HERE
   </h1>

    <div class="bg-container buttonContainer">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <div class="inline-choices cWidth"><img height="50%" width="50%" src="http://www.petpicturegallery.com/pictures/cats/funnycat/134-cat_funnycat_funny_cat_12.jpg" /> </div>
   <div class="inline-choices cWidth">
    <h4> I am trying to strech the red container to the width of yellow container. I think the issue springs from padding attribute. <br><br> <button class="buttonENC" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">H.W.</button></h4> </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.bg-container {
   padding-left: 10%;
   padding-right: 10%;
   background: yellow;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
 }

 .buttonContainer {
   background: red;
  }

 .inline-choices {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 30%;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the result your looking for, I think. Take a look and tell me if it's what you want.

```css
.bg-container {
  background: yellow;
 }
   .buttonContainer {
  background: red; 
    width: 100%;
 }
  .inline-choices {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
 }
  .header{
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg-container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>
   SOME LORUM HERE
  </h1>
    <HR>
    <H2>
   SOME IPSUM HERE 
  </H2>
</div>
  <div class="bg-container buttonContainer">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="inline-choices cWidth"><img height="50%" width="50%" src="http://www.petpicturegallery.com/pictures/cats/funnycat/134-cat_funnycat_funny_cat_12.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="inline-choices cWidth">
      <h4> I am trying to strech the red container to the width of yellow container. I think the issue springs from padding attribute. <br><br> <button class="buttonENC" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">H.W.</button></h4> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @John No problem! Welcome to stack overflow, if an answer worked for you please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Your method is perfect :) I don't however understand the logic behind it. I have never used .header{} css in this way before. I thought header was something above the body tag, and it could not be seen by the user in his browser. This shocks me a little, but what happens? how does it work? thanks again

Comment: .header is nothing special at all, it is just what I happened to name the div in the html. I could have had class="boop" in the html with .boop{} in the css and it would have done the same thing. What makes it work is that I added width: 100%; to your buttonContainer class and moved the padding from your bg-container to the .header so it doesn't move the buttonContainer . So you were right about padding causing the problem.

Comment: I see haha, it took me a sec to realized that the its wasnt <head>. anyway I just added the margin to my initial <body> tag. I think it might be the more elegant way for me at the moment :) appreciate all the help :)